# How to change a html class with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to Change a HTML class with JavaScript

HTML

```
<i id="test" class="fa">
```

How can I do it really simple?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use this in javascript:

```
 $("#test").removeClass("fa");
 $("#test").addClass("newClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

use [`.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) to add and also get class name of particular element.

```
document.getElementById('test').className = "fa";
```

Comment: typo there, you missed an "N" in getElementById

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property, you can also use the much more elaborate [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property and its methods:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('test');
ele.classList.remove('fa');
ele.classList.add('ba');
```

You can also `toggle()` classes (with optional conditions!) and hence easily do without jQuery’s `toggleClass()` and its other class-related methods (like shown in the [downvoted, accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31984451/2083613)).